# View the Alamofire POST http body as json

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I need to print the http POST or PUT json body that Alamofire encodes in the parameters field with the `JSONEncoding.default` encoder. Do anyone know how to do that in Swift?

Comment: On each request? You can use a `Interceptor` and print it. Or use the `cURLDescription` and print it (as it should appear there too).

Comment: Thanks! cURLDescription worked nicely